# vb.net visual drag tables from datasource (bd acces)

Tags: vb.net, dataset

I can, drag and drop visually one table at form in vb.net, alumno,asignatura,curso etc..

[image]

But my question are, i can drag to combobox for display all tables visually?
After, i can choose what table need show in new form.

Comment: You could program the combo box to change the datagridview based on the value of the combo box

Answer (score 0):

If using SQL-Server database you could create a stored procedure as shown below, then in the Data Source window, right click the data set name, select configure with wizard, add the new store procedure.

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE uspAllTableNames
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SELECT name FROM sys.objects WHERE type = 'U'
END
GO
```

Once that is done drag the stored procedure onto the form delete the binding navigator, add a combo box (in this case ComboBox1) and load it e.g.

Dim tableNames As New NorthWindDataSet.uspAllTableNamesDataTable

```
Me.UspAllTableNamesTableAdapter.Fill(tableNames)
ComboBox1.DataSource = tableNames
ComboBox1.DisplayMember = "Name"
```

From here access the current item via ComboBox1.Text

Screenshot where I did NorthWind database
[image]